# PowerShell Function "Get-DailyHelp" to Supply Random Daily Learning

Tags: powershell

I'm learning PS scripting.

Jeff Hicks suggested running the following each day to gain more knowledge - I really like this idea:

```
Get-Command -Module Microsoft*,PS* | Get-Random | Get-Help -ShowWindow
Get-Random -input (Get-Help about*) | Get-Help -ShowWindow
```

I want to add them to my `Profile.ps1` but only want them to run if I open PS between 8 and 11 each morning.

This want my attempt to create a simple function inside Profile - any criticism, additions or deletions would be welcome. A specific question I have is should the function sit inside Profile or better placed in a separate ps1 file that Profile calls?

```
function Get-DailyHelp {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [int]
    $HourToRunStart,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [int]
    $HourToRunEnd

  )
  begin {
    Write-Host "Help windows are created if you fire up PS between $HourToRunStart and $HourToRunEnd"
  }
  process {
    $HourNow = (get-date).ToLocalTime().TimeOfDay.Hours
    if ($HourNow -ge $HourToRunStart -and $HourNow -lt $HourToRunEnd) {

      $HelpLogPath = "C:\Users\Me\Location\Documents\Powershell"
      $HelpLogName = "HelpLogPath.txt"
      $HelpFullName = (Join-Path -Path $HelpLogPath -ChildPath $HelpLogName)

      # create file if it does not exist
      Set-Location -Path $HelpLogPath
      if (-not ($HelpFullName | Test-Path)){
        New-Item -ItemType "file" -Path (Join-Path -Path $HelpLogPath -ChildPath $HelpLogName) -Value (Get-Date)
      }

      $lastRun = [datetime]::Parse((Get-Content $HelpFullName), [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("En-GB"))
      $difference = New-TimeSpan -Start ($lastRun) -End (Get-Date)

      if ($difference.TotalMinutes -gt 60){
        
        # generate 3 windows to choose from
        foreach ($X in 1..3) {
          Get-Command -Module Microsoft*,PS* | Where-Object {$_.ModuleName -ne 'PSCX'} | Get-Random | Get-Help -ShowWindow
        }
        # generate a single about topic
        Get-Random -input (Get-Help about*) | Get-Help -ShowWindow

        # store the last run date time so it won't generate again if restarted within last 60 mins
        Set-Content -Path $HelpFullName -Value (Get-Date)

      }
    }
  }
  end {
  }
}
    
Get-DailyHelp -HourToRunStart 8 -HourToRunEnd 11
```